# Null values in df in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, syntax-error, keyerror

I am having problems with the following code:

```
for i in np.arange(37,finaldf.shape[0]):

# We choose to search by category with a 500m radius. radius = 500 LIMIT = 100 category_id = '4bf58dd8d48988d102951735' #ID for Accessory stores

latitude = finaldf['Latitude'][i] longitude = finaldf['Longitude'][i]

# Define the corresponding URL url = 'https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?client_id={}&client_secret={}&ll={},{}&v={}&categoryId={}&radius={}&limit={}'.format(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, latitude, longitude, VERSION, category_id, radius, LIMIT)

# Send the GET Request results = requests.get(url).json()

# Get relevant part of JSON and transform it into a pandas dataframe
# assign relevant part of JSON to venues venues = results['response']['venues']

# tranform venues into a dataframe dataframe = json_normalize(venues) dataframe.head()

# keep only columns that include venue name, and anything that is associated with location filtered_columns = ['name', 'categories'] + [col for col in dataframe.columns if col.startswith('location.')] + ['id'] dataframe_filtered = dataframe.loc[:, filtered_columns]

# function that extracts the category of the venue def get_category_type(row):
    try:
        categories_list = row['categories']
    except:
        categories_list = row['venue.categories']

    if len(categories_list) == 0:
        return None
    else:
        return categories_list[0]['name']

# filter the category for each row dataframe_filtered['categories'] = dataframe_filtered.apply(get_category_type, axis=1)

# clean column names by keeping only last term dataframe_filtered.columns = [column.split('.')[-1] for column in dataframe_filtered.columns]

print(str(i) + ') The number of shops in '
+finaldf['Neighbourhood'][i] + ' is ' +str(dataframe_filtered.shape[0]) + '\n') N_shop.append(dataframe_filtered.shape[0])
```

**This iteration makes me count for each neighborhood the number of stores that corresponds, but when executing it I get the following error:**

---

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-109-94d4817fe1e7> in <module>
      6     category_id = '4bf58dd8d48988d102951735' #ID for Accessory stores
      7 
----> 8     latitude = finaldf['Latitude'][i]
      9     longitude = finaldf['Longitude'][i]
     10 

/opt/conda/envs/Python36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py in __getitem__(self, key)
    866         key = com.apply_if_callable(key, self)
    867         try:
--> 868             result = self.index.get_value(self, key)
    869 
    870             if not is_scalar(result):

/opt/conda/envs/Python36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_value(self, series, key)
   4372         try:
   4373             return self._engine.get_value(s, k,
-> 4374                                           tz=getattr(series.dtype, 'tz', None))
   4375         except KeyError as e1:
   4376             if len(self) > 0 and (self.holds_integer() or self.is_boolean()):

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_value()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 38
```

The final df is composed of 5 columns and 39 rows in which the postal code, district, neighborhood, longitude and latitude are located since I will then use that data to locate them on the map. I have searched for null values, or have another type of format but I have not found any. What is wrong? Since from what I understand there is a row (the 38) that is the one that causes the error. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Can you share a proper [mcve], including information on your data? Have you read the Pandas docs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is very hard to answer without knowing the form of your dataframe, but I would guess your index contains integers, but not the specific value `38`, perhaps as the result of earlier filtering.  Pandas is probably interpreting `38` as a potential *label*, not an integer index.

From the pandas indexing documentation:

> `.ix` offers a lot of magic on the inference of what the user wants to do. To wit, `.ix` can decide to index positionally OR via labels depending on the data type of the index. This has caused quite a bit of user confusion over the years.

Your for-loop suggests you want to iterate over rows, so you could change it to use `.iloc`:

```
for i in np.arange(37, finaldf.shape[0]):
    latitude = finaldf['Latitude'].iloc[i]    # Use .iloc[i] 
    longitude = finaldf['Longitude'].iloc[i]
```

If you wanted to rewrite that in a clever way, you could try:

```
for lat, long in final_df[['Latitude', 'Longitude']].iloc[37:].iterrows():
    # Use lat, long   
    ...
```

This relies on Python's automatic unpacking to iterate through each row's Series.